# Orientation on ios 8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, orientation, ios8

I have 6 tabs in my iPad application, all of the controllers have a single baseViewController. In my first tab there is a collection view and different layouts for landscape and portrait mode. When I launch the application and rotate for the first time, all tabs' controllers are loaded simultaneously. Every time I rotate the device it calls orientation methods for all controllers. Before iOS 8 everything was working fine but this issue occurs only in iOS 8.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Could you please indicate which part of what you're describing is the problem?

Comment: When I launch app and rotates device then ViewDidLoad method of controllers are called.

Comment: Seems like that in itself isn't a problem, pretty sure it's expected behavior (UITabBarController creates and holds reference to all of its child viewControllers, maybe does some memory mgmt to unload / load)

Comment: I'm guessing this is just how it is going forward. Most likely a side effect of rotation being replaced with size changes. Given that, what is the impact to you based on this change? Lots of possible suggestions but need to know more about what you are seeing.